# send BroadcastReceiver request even if application not started yet

Tags: android

I understoo from docs that

> As of Android 3.1 the Android system will by default exclude all
>   BroadcastReceiver from receiving Intents if the corresponding
>   application has never been started by the user or if the user
>   explicitly stopped the application via the Android menu (in Manage
>   Application).

Thus, I wonder how could I send send Broadcast to Receiver if my app have not been started yet.

Comment: You simply can't. The user has to start your app at least once before. There is no way around this restriction.

Comment: I think you can explicitly start a not-yet-active or disabled app via [Context#startActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29). That would require a second active app under your control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Thus, I wonder how could I send send Broadcast to Receiver if my app have not been started yet.

I am going to take you literally, meaning that *you* want to send a broadcast `Intent` to some `BroadcastReceiver` that you wrote.

If the sender and the `BroadcastReceiver` are in the same app, there is no problem: if the sender is capable of running, it is capable of sending the broadcast. That's because the user will have had to do something to run the sender, such as starting an activity.

If the sender and the `BroadcastReceiver` are in different apps, my understanding is that the sender can include `FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES` on the `Intent` and that will make sure that the `BroadcastReceiver` in the other app can receive the broadcast.